# How to Lint code if I need additional mongodb request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, monk

Today I have this code. I learning NodeJS and all the time I have same question: I have a route. This route doing something, thats why I need some mongodb requests. In different ways I can need additional options or not. For example please look on my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const debug = require('debug')('hackit:posts');
const boom = require('boom');

const config = require('../../config');
const db = require('monk')(config.mdbConnect);
const DBpgs = db.get('pgs');
const DBposts = db.get('posts');
const DBcategories = db.get('categories');

router.route( "/edit-:id" )
  .get((req,res,next) => {
    const ops ={
      h1: "Edit post",
      title: "Admin edit post",
      description: "Admin page",
      specialscript: "/javascripts/editpost.js"
    };
    DBposts.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, saved) => {
      if(saved.h1.length) debug('Edit «'+saved.h1+'»')
      else debug('Create new post')
      if(err) next(boom.badImplementation(err))
      DBcategories.find({}, (err, categories) => {
        if(err) next(boom.badImplementation(err))
        let group = {}
        if(saved.parent&&saved.parent.length){
          DBpgs.findOne({parent: saved.parent}, (err, group) => {
            if(err) next(boom.badImplementation(err))
            res.render('admin/post', {ops, saved, categories, group})
          })
        }else{
          res.render('admin/post', {ops, saved, categories, group})
        }
      })
    })
  })

module.exports = router;
```

There is only one route. The problem is if I got `saved.parent` I need to do additional request to db, to pick `group` options. I solved it just by `if` and ... its looks rude. Next two lines i type `res.render('admin/post', {ops, saved, categories, group})` witch is the same line of code. I want to be a good programmer. Lint my code and say how I must fill my code please. Thanks!

Comment: Promises would help, as mongoose functions all return them as an alternative to callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The promise-based implementation would look something like this (I just modified your code directly in the answer so it probably has bugs, but it gives you the gist).  Note that you get out of duplicating both the response as well as the error conditions.

```
router.route( "/edit-:id" )
    .get((req,res,next) => {

        const ops ={
            h1: "Edit post",
            title: "Admin edit post",
            description: "Admin page",
            specialscript: "/javascripts/editpost.js"
        };

        DBposts.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
            .then(saved => {
                if (saved.h1.length) debug('Edit «'+saved.h1+'»');
                else debug('Create new post');
                return DBcategories.find({})
                    .then(categories => {
                    if (saved.parent && saved.parent.length) {
                        return DBpgs.findOne({parent: saved.parent});
                    }
                    return {};
                })
               .then(group => {
                   res.render('admin/post', {ops, saved, categories, group})
               })
               .catch(error => {
                   next(boom.badImplementation(err));
               });
            });
    });
```